# Google Maps fails when we upgrade our application's jQuery library

Tags: jquery, google-maps

We have an application running on jQuery 1.4.2 that we are slowly upgrading to jQuery 1.9.1

One of the pages we are upgrading now has a Google Map on it. The page, broadly speaking, contains...

```
<head>
  <script src="/javascripts/jquery-1.4.2.min.js?1362527887" type="text/javascript"></script>
  ...
  <script src="/javascripts/google_map.js?1362527225" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
  ...
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
      new GoogleMap($('#map_canvas'), '<%= APP_CONFIG['google_maps_api_key'] %>');
    });
  </script>
</body>
```

This loads jQuery, and then later loads the javascript file which initialises our Google map as follows:

```
GoogleMap = function (mapElement, apiKey) {
  this.initialized = false;
  this.mapElement = mapElement;
  $.getJSON('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=' + apiKey + '&sensor=false&callback=?', $.proxy(this.apiLoaded, this));
};

GoogleMap.prototype = {

  apiLoaded:function () {
    this.show();
    var mapOptions = this.defaultLocation();
    this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.mapElement[0], mapOptions);
    ...
  },

  ....
};
```

On jQuery 1.4.2, this all works. However, when we moved onto jQuery 1.9.1 (or any jQuery version between 1.6.3 and 1.9.1, for what it's worth) I see the following error in the Javascript console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Property 'jQuery191006026467704214156_1362528404472' of object [object Window] is not a function
```

This error occurs in main.js, a file that comes down when a google map is loaded via the above call. Changing the jQuery version from 1.4.2 to 1.4.3 works fine however - so it's not just "any change" that's breaking it.

A JSBin that recreates the error (although doesn't show the map, even with 1.4.2 in place, possibly as I cut too much out?) is here: http://jsbin.com/okirac/4/

Do I need to call google maps in a different way for later versions of jQuery? Or should I potentially be using jQuery in a different way to avoid clashes with google maps ?

Like I say, the maps work fine with jQuery 1.4.2 and a whole bunch of other javascript calls on the page. But the later versions of jQuery are breaking google maps on the page, whilst all the other javascript calls seem fine.

Comment: maybe you can make some seperate test cases in jsbin, that would be easier for you to debug and for us to help you :)

Comment: Great idea - thanks. Haven't played with JSBin before, but I put up something that recreates the error with jQuery 1.9.1, and doesn't show the error with jQuery 1.4.2. Can't get it to display the map, but that might be due to cutting out too much from the example (some CSS, perhaps).

Comment: something to do with this http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/ ?

Comment: My usage of .getJSON() DOES appear to be the problem - http://forum.jquery.com/topic/prroblem-with-jquery-getjson-anonymous-function-is-not-converted-to-global-after-updating-to-1-5-0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Capitaine and @i-- for their comments, I got it to work.

It seems that post-1.4.x jQuery, you can no longer rely on jQuery.getJSON() to work against Google Maps, which actually returns JS, not JSON (see my link in the original question's comments).

In the end, I used the [Google Maps documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial?hl=en#Loading_the_Maps_API) to change my in-page javascript code to:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    gmap = new GoogleMap($('#map_canvas'));

    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.src = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=<%= APP_CONFIG['google_maps_api_key'] %>&sensor=false&callback=gmap.apiLoaded";
    document.body.appendChild(script);
  });
</script>
```

This sets up a global "gmap" object, then defines a callback parameter on the Google Maps API, which means upon the Maps API being loaded it then calls the apiLoaded() function on my gmap object.

This then works with both older and newer versions of jQuery.